# How to change the default value of range slider by getting from a table value

Tags: javascript, html

How to set the range slider default value using javascript inline.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id='tab'>
  <tr> 
    <td>Lattitude</td>  
    <td>20</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr>  
    <td>Longitude</td> 
    <td>25</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>value</td>  
    <td id='val'>100</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
ON
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5" onchange="console.log(document.getElementById('tab').rows[2].cells.namedItem('val').innerHTML)">
OFF
```

In the above code I have hardcoded the value as 5 but if I want to change by getting the value from table data `value`(`document.getElementById('tab').rows[2].cells.namedItem('val').innerHTML`). How I can inject the default value.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302515/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-value-of-range-input-to-be-empty) could be helpful

Comment: how are you planning to inject it then ? a button ? event listener ? when do you want the script to populate value in table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which allows any valid CSS selector string as parameter.

You can try the following way:

```js
var rInput = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');

var val = document.querySelector('#tab tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').textContent;
rInput.value = val;
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id='tab'>
  <tr> 
    <td>Lattitude</td>  
    <td>20</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr>  
    <td>Longitude</td> 
    <td>25</td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
    <td>value</td>  
    <td id='val'>100</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
ON<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5">OFF
```

**Update:** As you have mentioned in the comment that you are not allowed to use *script* tag, solution using inline JavaScript:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="var rInput = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');var val = document.querySelector('#tab tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').textContent;rInput.value = val;">
  <table id='tab'>
    <tr> 
      <td>Lattitude</td>  
      <td>20</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>  
      <td>Longitude</td> 
      <td>25</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td>value</td>  
      <td id='val'>100</td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
  ON<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="5" >OFF

</body>
```

Comment: I was using one framework that is not supporting script tag as a separate. That's why is it possible inside input tag can we set value.

Comment: @vikram, I am not sure why the framework will not support that. Because the proper way of writing JavaScript is using the *script* tag. Though I have added another solution using the *onload* function in *body* tag....please check.

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving your slider an unique ID so we can access it using JavaScript

```
<input type="range" id="slider" min="0" max="100" value="5" onchange="console.log(document.getElementById('tab').rows[2].cells.namedItem('val').innerHTML)">
```

Now simply change it's value like this

```
<script "text/javascript">
document.getElementById('slider').value=parseInt(document.getElementById('tab').rows[2].cells.namedItem('val').innerHTML);
</script>
```