# Range start unpicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a range selecting from five values in an html page. I want the range to start "unpicked", meaning that the user will have to click on it, and not start with a default value already selected.

I'm using javascript, AngularJS and CSS. I've tried manipulating the default value and even the css, but I can't find a good solution.

I tried adding another value and using it as a default, but then I can't hide it and is overall not a good solution to my problem.

This is my current range:

```
<div id="rangeSelector" class="range mx-auto">
    <input id="rangeInput" type="range" min="1" max="5" steps="1" dir="rtl" ng-model="myIdealRate" ng-change="changeSelect()">
</div>
<ul class="range-labels mx-auto">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Now It automatically starts with the third value selected, but I want it to start with non selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set default value of range input to be empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302515/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-value-of-range-input-to-be-empty)

Comment: ok, but there is no _real_ solution there. is there maybe a way to hide the control variable?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb

Comment: Add another range value and set the label to default?

Comment: I already have that in my css, it doesn't help my problem though as I already tried changing it.

Comment: If add another value, how do I hide it from being seen/selected again?