# How to Change value of input after page loads?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, wordpress-theming

I have used a range picker (Progress bar) to get measurements from the customers. I have set it's limit from 1 to 50 so it takes 1 value by default if user do not select it and user can add product to the cart without selecting range picker.  Is there any way that we can change by default value on page load with javascript (No jQuery) to something that does not allow user to add product to the cart.

Link: https://cutt.ly/nrB4PAR

I am using this code now but it's not working. I want value to be null.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    debugger;

    var range_val = document.getElementById("tmcp_range_1").value;
    if (range_val == 1)
        {
         document.getElementById("tmcp_range_1").value = "";
        }
    
</script>
```

[image]

**UPDATED:**

[image]

Comment: I think you shouldn't change it like in your example. First of all, if you want to load value 22 on page load you should change the `value` attribute in your HTML, but when you want to trigger change default value on some action you need to pin this function to some kind of event. The problem with your function is that you don't initialize it anywhere, but logic seems to be correct.

Comment: i want it to be null.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Do you want to have `null` value by default on your range input? You show us an example that changes the value to 22 by default, so  I'm confused now, and I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want it to be null

Comment: You can't set null value to input.

Comment: lol why?? I have been trying this from last 2days?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302515/is-there-a-way-to-set-default-value-of-range-input-to-be-empty

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I really understand why you need this, but you have to put that code in a function, then call an event listener.

```
function changeVal() {
  var range_val = document.getElementById("tmcp_range_1").value;
  if (range_val == 1) {
    document.getElementById("tmcp_range_1").value = "22";
  }
}

window.addEventListner("load", changeVal);
```

Comment: No it's not working it's not changing the value to 22

Comment: I think it depends on the element you choose to target for the event listener, I guess. I set `window` in my example, but you can try other solutions. What you got in the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the input value after DOM loads will change the value.

```
function updateVal() {
    var range_val = document.getElementById("tmcp_range_1").value;
    if (range_val == 1) {
        document.getElementById("tmcp_range_1").value = "22";
    }
}
window.addEventListner("load", updateVal);
```

And also you need to change noUiSlider logic to update UI. 
Ref link https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/

Comment: You paste the same example as below and the author told that this solution didn't work in his case.